# Bitcoin Miner for HP application

Tags: blockchain

So, I installed Bitcoin miner from an app store already built into my HP computer. I've downloading blockchain to keep my bitcoin wallet but havent really used it all that much to know when im recieving this payout. I went to pay out address and put in my wallet code at the bottom and of course my barcode came up but i havent gotten any kind if confirmation yet or any enter button after entering my address.. Is there anyway i can know that the satoshis I am mining are going in my wallet? Please help

Comment: It would be useful to know the specific app that you are using for mining, its name. Generally, it is not economical to mine just on your computer but, the app may connect to a mining pool.